# Cannot invoke 'authenticate' with an argument list of type '(user: String, password: String)'

Tags: swift, xcode, twilio, alamofire

I'm trying to add a referral program to the app I am developing. The first step of doing this for me is to send users SMS messages from a phone number I have. To do this I am using Twilio and Alamofire, but I am getting this error: Cannot invoke 'authenticate' with an argument list of type '(user: String, password: String)'. I removed my tokens from my code, so here it is (I'm importing UIKit, Alamofire, and Foundation):

```
func sendMessage() {
    if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"],
       let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] {

      let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Messages"
      let parameters = ["From": "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", "To": "YOUR_PERSONAL_NUMBER", "Body": "Hello from Swift!"]

      AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .authenticate(user: accountSID, password: authToken)
        .responseJSON { response in
          debugPrint(response)
      }

      RunLoop.main.run()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely working from an older tutorial. `authenticate(user:password:)` was renamed to `authenticate(username:password:)` in Alamofire 5.

Answer (score 1):

welcome on board.

I think the problem is, arguments `accountSID` and `authToken` are not considered as String variables.

Maybe you should cast it in you condition, like that :

```
if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"] as? String,
       let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] as? String {
```

Dont you have any warning in your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried out optional and non-optional strings before posting this question and it worked with neither.